# How to display X-Bar statistics symbol in Java Swing label?

Tags: java, swing, unicode

What's the best way to insert statistics symbols in a `JLabel`'s text? For example, the x-bar? I tried assigning the text field the following with no success:

```
<html>x&#772;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Html codes will not work in Java.  However, you can use the unicode escape in Java `Strings`.

For example:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(new String("\u0304"));
```

Also, here is a [cool website](http://www.snible.org/java2/uni2java.html) for taking Unicode text and turning it into Java String leterals.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's completely mal-formed HTML, probably even for Swing (I think you would need the `</html>` at the end for it to work. But I would try to never go that road if you can help it, as Swing's HTML support has many drawbacks and bugs.

You can probably simply insert the appropriate character directly, either directly in the source code if you're using Unicode or with the appropriate Unicode escape:

```
"x\u0304"
```

This should work, actually. But it depends on font support and some fonts are pretty bad in positioning combining characters. But short of drawing it yourself it should be your best option.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain `x̄` in adding `\u0304` to `x` character.

In your case, you must generate following string

```
"x\u0304"
```

The character [\u0304](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0305/index.htm) alone is only a overscore or overline character. It is a special `Diacritic` character in UNICODE table. You can use it in combination with other normal character to obtain a composite character.

You can find more information on Diacritics characters at following location [//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character)

You can also use

- [\u0305](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0307/index.htm) to have a longer bar
- [\u0307](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0308/index.htm) to have a dot above previous character (speed in mechanic)
- [\u0308](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0309/index.htm) to have 2 dots above previous character (accelaration in
  mechanic)
- [\u0325](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/030A/index.htm) to have a circle above previous character

Example

```
"[x\u0305]" -> x̄
"[z\u0307]" -> x̅
"[t\u0308]" -> ṫ
"[u\u0309]" -> ü
"[A\u030A]" -> Å
```

In example, only x overlapped with long bar is not correctly displayed in HTML because Chrome browser has a bug (I think).

If you Paste/Copy correctly displayed character in MS Word, you will see correct display of all these characters.

To type a new overlined character in MS Word, you type the character and immediately after you press <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>&</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> where 0774 is the base 10 representation of diacritic overline character.